# chrome.browserAction, disabling Icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to disable or enable my chrome extension based on the matches of the content scripts, but I think there is a better way.  Below is my code.  Seems like what I am attempting to accomplish could be achieved by ***chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged*** but that does not seem to fire consistently.

```js
    const IsMatch = (tab, matches) => {
     if (tab ==undefined && tab == null && tab.url == undefined){
      return false;
    }
    
    for(var ctr = 0; ctr < matches.length ; ctr ++){
      var match = matches[ctr].substring(0, matches[ctr].length - 1);
      if (tab.url.startsWith(match) ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
    }
  
  

    const updateIcon = tabId => {
        chrome.browserAction.disable();
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
            var contentScripts = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts;
            for(var i = 0; i < contentScripts.length ; i ++){
              var contentScript = contentScripts[i];
              if ( IsMatch(tabs[0], contentScript.matches) ) {
                chrome.browserAction.enable();
                console.log('chrome.tabs.query');
                console.log(tabs[0]);
                return;
              }
            }
        });
      };
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updateIcon);
```

After the changes recommended by @wOxxOm I am now in a race condition here is the **updated code**

```js
     browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {  
        if (request.message === 'enableIcon') {
          console.log(sender.tab.id + ' ' + request.message);
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({tabId: sender.tab.id, path: 'icon-16.png'});
          browser.browserAction.enable();
        }
        return true;
      });
    
      browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId) {
        console.log(tabId + ' disableIcon');
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({tabId: tabId, path: 'icon-16-Disabled.png'});
        chrome.browserAction.disable();
      });
```

Here is the ouput:

```
 - 6: backgroundIcon.js:31 39 disableIcon
 - 1: backgroundIcon.js:22 39 enableIcon
 - 2: backgroundIcon.js:31 39 disableIcon
```

Comment: You can simply call disable once at the start of the extension and then send a message from your content script so that the background script onMessage will call chrome.browserAction.enable(sender.tab.id).

Comment: @wOxxOm Updated the code now I am in a race condition. IT appears to be on the right track.

Comment: Oops, disabling by default would be better achieved by removing "default_popup" from manifest.json, then in your onMessage you would call chrome.browserAction.setPopup({tabId: sender.tab.id, popup: 'popup.html'}) and additionally you can set "default_icon" in manifest.json to a disabled icon, then use chrome.browserAction.setIcon in onMessage to set an enabled icon.

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you   To summarize in the manifest set everything to disabled and in the content script sendMessage to enable it on the back ground script.